# IndexOutOfBoundsException in scala code

Tags: scala

I have arraybuffer with 1 or 2 elements:
like: `ArrayBuffer(Some(one point), Some(two point))`
if both elements are available I don't have problem.
but Only first element is exist then how to check whether 2nd is exist or not.

I m using like:

```
if(times.get(1)==null){
 val time = times.get(1)
} else{
 val time = times.get(0)
}
```

but `times.get(1)` is throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when only 1 element is exist.

Comment: Are you sure you want None if your last element is None? May be you did mean `times.get(1)!=null`

Comment: I've just looked at your history. I can understand when new people only ask questions. But did you know that you can accept answers? If the answer solves your problem you are welcome to mark it as accepted. Are you sure that none of your questions was solved? It will be very nice if you will review those answers and either accept or comment why given answer doesn't solve your problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As usual in almost any language you can avoid such an exception by checking the size of the collection:

```
if (times.size >= 2 && times.get(1) == null) times.get(1) else times.get(0)
```

However, a more scala way to do that for any sized collection would be:

```
val time = times.reverse.collectFirst { case Some(t) => t }
```

This will find the last nonEmpty time in your collection and return it as 'Options'.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following snippet

```
times.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.get).lastOption
```

Let's look closer at every step:

`times.filter(_.nonEmpty)` filters out empty elements

`.map(_.get)` maps Some(x) to x, as at this point we're sure that we only have non empty elements

`.lastOption` returns either Some(x) in case of non empty list where x is last element, either None if list was empty

Answer (score 0):

Possible (not very scala like) approach also could be:

If you are sure that at least one object exists you may use scala Try:

```
val time = Try {
    if (times.get(1) == null) {
        times.get(1)
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException
    }
} getOrElse times.get(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `flatMap` as follows,

```
Array(1,null).flatMap(x => Option(x)).last
```

or `flatten` as follows,

```
Array(Some(1),Option(null)).flatten.last
```

With the flattening functions we keep only `Some` values and skim `null` or `None`. Note also `xs.flatten` is in fact `xs.flatMap(identity)`, namely `xs.flatMap(x => x)`